# How to know which SSID I am connected in Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file, netsh

For now, I have 2 batch file which turns on and off proxy using Registry Editor

Like

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ^
/v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

But, I read some where that it is possible to turn on or off proxy based on the network you are connected? So, if I can get the SSID name I can keep this in if else condtion

Comment: `netsh wlan show interface | findstr "SSID"`

Comment: Nice work. But, I am new to batch file. Do you have any idea how to fetch value of "SSID" ?? Do I need to use string operation to check my network name is there or something like key value exist? Either way I don't know how to proceed? Any good article if or any help?

Comment: I need SSID. Now I can proceed further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply get the `SSID` do:

```
netsh wlan show interface | findstr /i "SSID"
```

to set the first one as a variable use a for loop (assuming you do not want to use the mac address):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| findstr /i "SSID"') do set "myssid=%%i" & goto next
:next
set "myssid=%myssid: =%"
if /i "%myssid%"=="Spektrum" (
  reg add ....
)
if /i "%myssid%"=="someotherSSID" (
  reg add ....
)
```

To complete your code as is:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| findstr /i "SSID"') do set "myssid=%%i" & goto next
:next
echo %myssid%
set "myssid=%myssid: =%"
echo %myssid%
if /i "%myssid%"=="Spectrum" (
   echo "Spectrum"
 ) ELSE (
   echo "Other"
)
```