# How to assign the SSID of current connected wifi network to a variable in a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd, command-prompt

I'm trying to write a batch script that disconnects from a wifi network and after some time reconnects to the same network. In this case it have to remember the previously connected network SSID, like storing that into a variable.

```
netsh wlan disconnect
timeout 5
netsh wlan connect name=PreviousNetwork
```

I can find SSID name from

```
netsh wlan show networks interface="Wi-Fi" mode=ssid
```

But how can I store it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know which SSID I am connected in Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54860323/how-to-know-which-ssid-i-am-connected-in-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approch, just give a try :

```bat
@echo off
Title How to assign the SSID of current connected wifi network to a variable in a batch script
for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%n in (
'netsh wlan show interface name="Wi-Fi" ^| find /i "PROFIL"'
) do set "Network=%%n"
Call :Trim "%Network%" Connected_SSID
echo The Current SSID Connected is : "%Connected_SSID%"
echo Did you want to disconnect from this SSID "%Connected_SSID%" ?
pause
cls & echo( & color 0C
netsh wlan disconnect
TimeOut /T 5 /NoBreak>nul
cls & echo( & color 0A
echo Did you want to re-connect to this SSID : "%Connected_SSID%" ?
pause
netsh wlan connect name="%Connected_SSID%"
Pause & Exit
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Trim <String>
(
    echo Wscript.echo Trim("%~1"^)
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "%2=%%a" 
exit /b
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Whats with the vbscript?  Its needlessly forcing you to write to disk. Just change your trim function to:  `for /f "tokens=*" %%_ IN ("%~1") DO SET "%2=%%_"`  No need for VBScript or writing to disk.

Comment: @BenPersonick This works only with the Left Trim ?? and i want to trim left and right !

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I wrote this on my phone, and didn;t see your reply I just wrote my code a bit off, use this instead:   `for /f "tokens=*" %%_ IN ("%~1") DO SET "%2=%%~nx_"`  There is no need to use VB or write to disk this will trim right and left for your purposes.  TBF you don't even need to call the label `for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%_ in ('netsh wlan show interface name="Wi-Fi" ^| find /i "PROFIL"') do set "Network=%%~nx_"`

Comment: Actually, in addition, since SSIDs can not contain spaces themselves, you could actually just pass the result to the label call without surrounding quotes and then return it, since %1 will then be only be the continuous non-white-space characters.